# Access RGB intensity values in matlab?

Tags: matlab, rgb

Having some issues figuring this out. I have a 488x520x3 RGB image. If I'm wanting to address the R, G, or B intensity value at a specific pixel number (x,y)...how does one do this?

Thanks all

Comment: What is the representation of your image? Note that there is more than one way to represent an image in matlab.  Do you have a 2D matrix of values and a corresponding color map?

Comment: It's a .tif that's mxnx3, in this case <488x520x3> double

Comment: Then `myimage(x,y,:)` should be a row vector that tells you the RGB values respectively at pixel (x,y)

Comment: Most likely, `im(y, x, 1)` for red, `2` for green, `3` for blue will be what you're looking for.

Comment: @nispio, y is the first, x the second dimension.

Comment: I posted because this is what I was trying, but not getting the same values when I impixelinfo over that same point.

ex, y=img_data(66,100,:) doesn't yield the same as impixelinfo over the 66,100 location

Comment: Then try `img_data(100,66,:)`. Images are referenced from the top-left corner with the first dimension being the vertical axis (pointing down) and the second being the horizontal axis (pointing right). The fact that `impixelinfo` shows the (x,y) instead of (i,j) only serves to confuse the issue more.

Comment: Ahhhhh! Thanks!

So...obvious....X_X

Comment: If the problem is resolved, please mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A pixel that is `m` pixels from the top and `n` pixels from the left can be referenced as

```
rgb_vals = img_data(m,n,:);
```

Where the three elements of `rgb_vals` represent red, green, and blue respectively.  This is because you are indexing using matrix notation (row, column) rather than cartesian coordinates (x,y).